# How to show spinner or progress while data(pdf) is being loaded in HTML Object element from an URL

Tags: html, css, angular

I am Loading PDF in Object element in Angular/HTML and i want to show Spinner or Loader or Progress for Object element, while data is being loaded

```
<object  [attr.data]="protectedUrl" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a  and then create isLoaded var which will be true after getting loading data from url.

```js
getPdfDataFromUrl(clientId){
setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoaded=true;
        }, 3000);
let protectedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('xxxxxx'+clientId);
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded">
<object  [attr.data]="protectedUrl" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
<ng-container>
```

This will show your object only when pdf is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner) library, it is very easy to use. Few helpful links [usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner#usage) and [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kruvnm). If any other help is required please comment.